# Increasing the screen saver delay on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, screen, monitor

The max screen saver delay on Ubuntu 17.10 seems to be 15 minutes.  Is there a way to increase to say 45 minutes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 2700
```

Alternatively you can install `dconf-editor` and use it to browse to this value and set it, if you prefer a GUI approach.

After settings this, the gnome settings dialog will list a value of "never" for this key. I haven't tried waiting for 45 minutes to see if it indeed does what one would expect.

### Side note

How did I find out? I dumped my current gsettings using the following command:

```
for s in $(gsettings list-schemas); do for k in $(gsettings list-keys $s); do echo -n "$s/$k: "; gsettings get $s $k; done; done >gsettings.1
```

Then changed the setting using the gnome settings dialog. Then ran the command again, but replace `gsettings.1` with `gsettings.2`, to dump again the settings into another file.

Afterwards I could use diff like this to see which key was changed:

```
diff gsettings.1 gsettings.2
1883c1883
< org.gnome.desktop.session/idle-delay: uint32 900
---
> org.gnome.desktop.session/idle-delay: uint32 600
```